# How does the following EF MVC 5 code for sorting work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder){


   ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
   ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
   var students = from s in db.Students
                  select s;
   switch (sortOrder)
   {
      case "name_desc":
         students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
         break;
      case "Date":
         students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
         break;
      case "date_desc":
         students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
         break;
      default:
         students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
         break;
   }
   return View(students.ToList());
}
```

1. The ternary operators merely return one of the results based on the condition, they do not change sortOrder right?
2. If sortOrder is "Date" then the code sets the `ViewBag.DateSortParm`  to "date_desc" but isn't sortOrder still "Date" so it won't actually change the order?

I don't see how it is possible for this code to work correctly but it does.

Comment: 1. That's right the ternary returns "date_desc" if SortOrder is equal to Date otherwise it defaults to "Date". 2. From what I can see in the case of "date_desc" its ordering descending by enrollment date and in the case of "Date" its ordering ascending by  Enrollment Date. Unless the view bag is doing some ordering on the view itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The ternary operators just set a ViewBag value, yes. They don't alter the content of the `sortOrder` variable. In fact quite the opposite - they decide what to do *based on* the value of `sortOrder`.

2) You're right it doesn't have any effect on the way `students` actually gets sorted, which is determined by the `switch` statement.

The reason the ViewBag parameter values are set to the opposite of what you might expect are because in the View they are used to build hyperlinks which, when clicked, will cause the data to be sorted the opposite way to what it is now. e.g. if currently sorting "Date" (Date ascending), then it will construct a link which, if clicked, will pass back an instruction to the server to re-sort and return the data, but this time sorted by "date_desc" (Date descending) instead. So it does make sense, if you take into account what those values are used for later on.

Comment: Yes, if you look at the view in the quoted example they are just offering the display of the alternate sort to the one that is currently displayed - look at the view code.

Comment: @PeterSmith I did indeed just take a look (although really that code ought to have been part of the question, since context is important!) and have updated my answer to reflect the same conclusion you've pointed out.